# Error , while pushing element from mongodb to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop, object

Geting error while pushing an element to an array using for loop

***MY CODE***

```
router.get('/cart', verifyLogin, async (req, res) => {
 
  
    var products = await userHelpers.getCartProducts(req.session.user._id)
    console.log("quantity of 1 product:"+products[0].quantity);
    console.log("price of 1 product"+products[0].product.Price);
    console.log("length of cart:"+products.length);
    
 
  var numberOfProducts
  var proNum=[]
  var productsList=0


  for(numberOfProducts=0 ; numberOfProducts<=products.length; numberOfProducts++)
  
  { 
      console.log("price of product ****"+ products[numberOfProducts].product.Price);
    
      proNum[productsList]=products[numberOfProducts].product.Price
      productsList++
     
 
  }
  
 
   let totalValue=proNum.reduce((accumulator,currentValue)=>{
     return accumulator+currentValue
   },0)
  /////////

  
  
  res.render('user/cart', { products, user: req.session.user, totalValue })
  
}
```

when printing the value of `products[0].product.Price` ,it is giving correct value .But when it comes to the body of for loop, it is showing an error

THE ERROR

```
quantity of 1 product:3
price of 1 product100000
length of cart:3
price of product ****100000
price of product ****65000
price of product ****6509
(node:6604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Bimal Boby\Desktop\E-commerce-Website\routes\user.js:107:71
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(node:6604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6604) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(numberOfProducts=0 ; numberOfProducts<=products.length; numberOfProducts++)
```

should be

```
for(numberOfProducts=0 ; numberOfProducts < products.length; numberOfProducts++)
```

You should be using `<` instead of `<=` because `<` checks for array 0 1 2 while `<=` checks for array 0 1 2 3, while you only have 3 products.

This happens because array index starts from 0, while your `.length` is a counter.